# How can I select the child-element of an element, which has an ID to add or remove attributes?

Tags: javascript, mobile, attributes, html5-video

I have a situation in which I want to add/remove attributes from a video element to show different videos depending on the viewport. As you probably all know it's not sufficient to use "display: none" in order to not load a video on mobile. In my case, I want to load a different background video on mobile devices. My issue is, that I cannot edit the ID or class of that video, but only the parent-element, in this case, a section.

Given a certain viewport, let's say below 900px, I'd like to remove the autoplay attribute from said video element. It could look like this:

```
    window.onload = addAutoplay();
    var videoLocation  = document.firstElementChild("video-section-desktop");
    function addAutoplay() {
        if(window.innerWidth <992){
            videoLocation.removeAttribute("autoplay");
      };
    }
```

In this case, the inspect code looks like this:

```
<div id="video-section-desktop"><video src="..." loop autoplay muted playsinline></video></div>
```

My JS-Code up there is only able to select the parent-, but not the child-element (aka the video-element), and all of my tries to modify the code, did not end up in a working solution. I'm only familiar with HTML and CSS. JS is pretty new for me.

Thank you in advance and kind Regards!

---

To change the attributes of a child element (video) via JS, which I cannot edit otherwise

Comment: is `document.querySelector` what you're looking for? or `element.querySelector` when looking inside `element` only

Comment: I tried that one, but I didnt find a way to select the video. Its also only about this video. I do have other videos on the page, which I do not want to change :(

Comment: what did you try? `document.querySelector('#video-section-desktop > video')` ?

Comment: A different variant of that, but yours sadly also did not work for me :/
Used it like this
"window.onload = addAutoplay();
 var videoLocation  = document.querySelector('#video-section-desktop > video');
 function addAutoplay() {
  if(window.innerWidth <992){
  videoLocation.removeAttribute("autoplay");
   };
 }"

Comment: any errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are facing an issue with the `autoplay()` function when you call it because the functions is being called before the variable is defiened on the `window.onload`, and the variable `videoLocation` is acually needed to apply `removeAttribute("autoplay")` on it which will lead to an error as you are calling a method on `undefined` value.

And for selecting the video's parent element you tried to use `firstElementChild` which is actually not a function, its only a property that should actually be used on the parent element node to access the video, you can do it this way:

so this will get the parent element of the video:
`document.getElementById("video-section-desktop")`

While this will get the video itself in order to apply you functionality:
`document.getElementById("video-section-desktop").firstElementChild;`

Also, to `autoplay` a video in chromium browsers its recommanded to add `muted` attribute to the `video` tag to ensure that it will autoplay otherwise it might not work as expected according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

So your functionality should work after this adjustment:

HTML:

```
<div id="video-section-desktop">
     <video src="video.mp4" autoplay muted></video>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
const videoLocation = document.getElementById("video-section-desktop").firstElementChild;

    window.onload = addAutoplay();

    function addAutoplay() {
        if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
            videoLocation.removeAttribute("autoplay");
        }
    }
```

I hope this is what you are looking for and I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! Apologies for my poor understanding of JS!

If I may ask, how would you approach it, when you'd like to change the src-attribute of the video in that scenario? Based on the viewport. Lets say everything under 900w the src should be X and everything above 900w the src should be Y. That would be the ideal solution, as I noticed that the previous one will still cause other issues for my page. In that scenario the start-link of the video would be "#", so the video-tag gets created by my builder, but there is no preloading of the big file.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well it depends on your feature you are building, but I think I would do the same as you did to switch the `src` attribute when the viewport is diffrent on the onload stat. And also I think giving a default `src` value as "#" is a good approach because if you use another default value for an already existing video will lead to some perfomance issues if the viewport doesn't match the video you want to show.